# Arcadia Cursive REPL setup

Tags: unity-game-engine, clojure, clr, cursive

I'm following these instructions:
https://github.com/arcadia-unity/Arcadia/wiki/Using-IntelliJ-Cursive-with-Arcadia#getting-the-repl-working

but starting the REPL appears to stall at the last step:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.easy=false -Dmaven.wagon.rto=10000 "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=59490:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin" -classpath /Users/adriansmith/.lein/self-installs/leiningen-2.9.1-standalone.jar clojure.main -m leiningen.core.main run
```

[image: starting repl process stalled]
my run configuration for the starting repl is here: [image: https://i.imgur.com/BaUaaGD.png]

How do I get the bridge REPL to start?